# Missing application page mapped folder

Tags: application-pages, mapped-folder

I added an application page to my project and it (should have) generated the mapped folder under layouts. I can see it in my local folder and in Visual studio, but the folder and the application page are not being pushed to the server on deployment. What gives?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind! Make sure the feature is included in Package.package. In my case, at least.